# BSON object size of document retrieved from DB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

Mongo shell have [the bsonsize() method](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous) to get BSON size of a given document retrieved from DB.

Is there any way of getting the same using PyMongo driver? I have found the [bson module](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html) in the documentation but it is not fully clear to me how to use it to get the size of a document retrieved from DB.

Comment: Perhaps something like `len(bson.BSON.encode(document))`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on @SSDMS suggestion (thanks!) the following can be used:

```
len(bson.BSON.encode(document))
```

I have tested with a couple of documents in my DB, comparing the result at mongo shell and with the above Python method and getting the same result:

At mongo shell:

```
> var doc1 = db.entities.findOne({'_id.id': '001'})
> var doc2 = db.entities.findOne({'_id.id': '002'})
> Object.bsonsize(doc1)
816
> Object.bsonsize(doc2)
819
```

At Python console:

```
>>> import bson
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> db = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> doc1 = db['orion']['entities'].find_one({'_id.id': '001'})
>>> doc2 = db['orion']['entities'].find_one({'_id.id': '002'})
>>> len(bson.BSON.encode(doc1))
816
>>> len(bson.BSON.encode(doc2))
819
```

Comment: mongo have restriction of 16 MB for a document, may I know it this return number in python is in unit of MB or B?

Comment: I think is in bytes

Comment: Can confirm it's bytes